# Eigenvalue of rank 1 perturbation $\lim_{n \to \infty}(A-n u v^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Suppose $A \in \mathcal M(n \times n)$, $u, v \in \mathbb C^n$ are fixed and $u$ is not an eigenvector of $A$. What will be the eigenvalue of following limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (A-nuv^*).
\end{align*}
Is it minus infinity?

Comment: By $uv^*$ do you mean the outer (not inner) product? In either case the limit will not generally exist. I guess you are asking what happens to the eigenvalues as $n\rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: $uv^*$ would be an $n \times n$ matrix by ordinary matrix multiplication. Yes, my question is exactly the eigenvalues when $n \to \infty$.